# Which is the function that this sequence of functions converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Prove that $$ \left(\sqrt x, \sqrt{x + \sqrt x},  \sqrt{x +  \sqrt {x + \sqrt x}}, \ldots\right)$$ in $[0,\infty)$ is convergent and I should find the limit function as well.

For give a idea, I was plotting the sequence and it's look like[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** The limit function $f$, where it exists, should satisfy $(f(x))^2=x+f(x)$.

For existence, perhaps use the fact that an increasing sequence that is bounded above converges.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(x)$ is limited by $\sqrt{x}+1$ as can be shown easily by $induction$.

For the limit $y=f(x)$ we have the following :

$\sqrt{x+y}=y$

$x+y=y^2$

$0=y^2-y-x$

$\Delta=   1+4x                    $

$ So $  ,   $y=f(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$  for $x>0$ and  $f(0)=0 $
.